Does Schedule 7 of the Terrorism Act 2000 require one to hand over passwords to remote services?
It is reported than some people are being required to hand over their social media passwords
at airports under schedule 7 of the Terrorism Act 2000.
From a google the UK counter terrorism police say:

Can the police demand passwords for electronic devices?
Yes. If a person is being examined, they can be required to provide any information requested, including passwords and PINs to any electronic devices. They will commit an offence if they wilfully fail to comply with this requirement.

It seems to me that there is a fundamental difference between a "passwords and PINs to any electronic devices", which I interpret as being required by a device physically carried, and "social media passwords" which are required to access a third party service hosted remotely.
Does Schedule 7 of the Terrorism Act 2000 require one to hand over access credentials for remote services such as social media passwords in the same way it does to access credentials for electronic devices carried on ones person?

Given the state of social media this could be considered a kind of virtual cavity search, to be performed only with virtual rubber gloves. ;-)

Yes, with some qualifications/caveats.
Schedule 7 Terrorism Act 2000 is broadly written. It states that the person must "give the examining officer any information in his possession which the officer requests".
Quoting from the gov.uk guidance for Examining officers and review officers under Schedule 7 to the Terrorism Act 2000, the limits are:


The examining officer may only stop and question a person for the purpose of allowing a determination of whether that person appears to be someone who is or who has been concerned in the commission, preparation or instigation of acts of “terrorism” as defined in section 1 of the Terrorism Act 2000 or for the purpose of determining whether a person’s presence in the border area is connected with the person’s entry into, or departure, from, Northern Ireland. ...




Schedule 7 powers must be exercised in a manner which is proportionate to the legitimate aim and which does not unlawfully discriminate against anyone on the grounds of age, race (including colour, nationality, ethnic or national origin), religion or belief, gender or sexual orientation. ...




An examining officer may not ask a question under paragraph 2 or 3 of Schedule 7 where they have reasonable grounds to believe that the answer to the question would require a person to disclose or confirm the identity of a source of journalistic information or disclose information subject to legal privilege. ...


